# Quantum Image Processing Application

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, matlab

I have been reading about Quantum Wavelet transform and finding some problems. One of its application is that image is given as input and same image is retrieved as output with reduced size(Please correct me if I am wrong). I am able to find the functions in Qiskit to load the image data. I am not sure, how to convert the image into data, which can be loaded on to the quantum circuit? Please could someone explain me this process?  Is there some MATLAB code do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good place to start is [the chapter on quantum image processing in Qiskit Texbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/image-processing-frqi-neqr.html). It introduces possible representations as well as some working code.

A popular format for quantum storage of image data is FRQI. The chapter linked above treats about it in practice, though the [original paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=A%20flexible%20representation%20of%20quantum%20images%20for%20polynomial%20preparation,%20image%20compression,%20and%20processing%20operations&hl=pl&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) could be useful if you are interested in the intuition behind this format.

Comment: Thank you @3yakuya. Your links are good starting point.